# Mame really slow?

Tags: mame

mame is really slow on my netbook when it was running windows 7 mame ran at full speed, but after I installed lubuntu it runs at about 30%. I think I have all the right drivers how can i make it go full speed again?

Here's the results of  lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0624
Kernel driver in use: gma500
```

Comment: You did not mention which graphics do you have. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Gateway-Series-LT4010U-1-6GHz-Starter/dp/B00AKHO2QQ

Comment: It is GMA3600. It will never work well on Linux. Intel dropped support.

Comment: So it's unfixable?

Comment: I am afraid not.

Comment: Will switching to xubuntu help?

Comment: No, It will not. You can try to search the net using that adapter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Lubuntu 15.10 on a DELL Dimension 3000 and have Intel Graphics Drivers ONLY with basic hardware. I've been able to MAME work full speed from a slow running state doing the following below:

```
mame -mt -sdlvideofps -video soft -rs
```

**Here's the output I got from the last ROM I tested: [Workaround]**

3.48s,   22 F, avrg game:  6.32 FPS 158.22 ms/f, avrg video:  6.52 FPS 153.31 ms/f, last video:   inf FPS 139.97 ms/f
**Average speed: 100.00% (15 seconds)**

**Try some of these options listed here to tweak your system's MAME on Terminal to run optimized.**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mame.1.html

Then use the following default settings inside this file to permanently setup your mame.ini to run the settings you customized in Terminal:

```
sudo gunzip /usr/share/doc/mame/examples/default.mame.ini.gz
```

**ADDITIONAL ASSISTANCE YOU CAN TRY TO FIX THE ISSUE I HAD WITH MAME:**

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315336

Comment: "mame -mt -sdlvideofps -video soft -rs" Helped alot :) could you give me your .ini file?

Comment: File was uploaded successfuly on TinyUpload.com server:

You can download it from address: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=92161144191120444346

You can delete file from address: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?del_id=02137953690775552504


I'm using video opengl, if that doesn't work, use video soft instead in that mame.ini

Answer (score 0):

As you don't say, I guess your `netbook` has `Intel` graphics.

You will never get the speeds you got in Windows on Ubuntu with those graphics, the support from Intel is just not there for the drivers.

You say

> but after I installed lubuntu it runs at about 30%.

You would get better performance with `xubuntu` as `lubuntu` is very striped down and not meant or gaming at all, you could potentially see a good increase in performance with `xubuntu`, only use `lubuntu` if you must on your hardware.

Thanks to @pilot6 for pointing out, newer kernel has good drivers for newer `Intel` chips with `mesa` but the older `GMA` chips have poor support, as you never mentioned the GPU you have, I don't know what chip you have, but as you are using `lubuntu` I am just guessing your chip is older.

Comment: That is not true for all Intel graphics, only for low-end GMA that lacks good support in Linux. Intel HD graphics is really well supported.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have a a HD3000 laptop (few years old) and the performance is no where close that of windows, could you tell me what versions are working well? just a rough range, I will update the answer, I just don't have the hardware to check it.

Comment: The newer kernel and mesa is the better. Intel develops open source drivers and they get improvements. Like Ubuntu 15.10 or 14.04.4.

Comment: But GMA never works well in Linux.